# Spacebar triggering click event on checkbox?

Tags: javascript, html

If you spacebar on a checkbox, it checks the box. Everything was fine until I decide to disable the click event on the parent div, which I realized, disabled the spacebar on the checkbox as well!

```js
div1.addEventListener("click",function (e) {
  if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
  e.cancelBubble = true;
  return false;
}, true);
```

```html
<div id="div1">
    <input id="chk1" type="checkbox">
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0t01252x/1/

How can I prevent that? It seems like a very odd behaviour to me. Click events are click events, not keyboard events...

Note: tested with chrome and FF

Edit: worst: outputing the event in the console gives a ... MouseEvent!

Comment: what is the behavior you are looking for?

Comment: I'm with you here, I wouldn't have expected that. Maybe browser vendors thought this was a good idea? Like when they changed the keycode of the `[enter]` key on the far right of the keyboard to be the same as the one near the center.

Comment: @jmore009, keyboard events should not be disabled, only click events

Comment: Why is spacebar allowed, but not click?

Comment: So, a way to filter is to check the event's x/clientX and y/clientY coordinates. On a "spacebar click", the x and y are set to 0. But that's a dirty trick and not garanteed to work tomorrow morning when you wake up...

Comment: filed a bug, I really want to hear what the devs say about it. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1120106

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> [**Quirksmode - click, mousedown, mouseup, dblclick**](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/click.html)
>
> The click event fires when the user clicks on an element OR activates an element by other means **(i.e. the keyboard)** ... “click” event is really a misnomer: it should be called the “activate” event.

To work around this, you can attach a `click` *and* `keyup` event to the checkbox.

```
checkbox.addEventListener("click", handleCheckboxEvent, true);
checkbox.addEventListener("keyup", handleCheckboxEvent, true);
```

Listen to both events, and always disable the default behavior. From there, you can determine if the spacebar fired a `keyup` event if the key `32` is pressed (`e.keyCode === 32`).

If so, manually check the checkbox if it is **not** checked, and uncheck it if it **is** checked.

```
function handleCheckboxEvent(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (e.keyCode === 32) {  // If spacebar fired the event
        this.checked = !this.checked;
    }
}
```

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/hvfo4w1q/) - tested in the latest versions of Chrome/FF/IE.

```js
(function () {
    var checkbox = document.getElementById('checkbox');

    function handleCheckboxEvent(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (e.keyCode === 32) {  // If spacebar fired the event
            this.checked = !this.checked;
        }
    }

    checkbox.addEventListener("click", handleCheckboxEvent, true);
    checkbox.addEventListener("keyup", handleCheckboxEvent, true);
})();
```

```html
<input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" />
```

Comment: Ok, so you're manually overriding the built-in behavior. To some extent, this is an acceptable workaround I believe...

Answer (score 4):

Kaiido seems to have a good solution. As for the behavior this is apparently expected. According to:

[**W3C - SCR35: Making actions keyboard accessible by using the onclick event of anchors and buttons**](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/SCR35)

the `onclick` event is triggered by the keyboard for accessibility purposes. Browsers use the click event even if its triggered from the keyboard in the event that a mouse isnt present:

> While "onclick" sounds like it is tied to the mouse, the onclick event
>   is actually mapped to the default action of a link or button. The
>   default action occurs when the user clicks the element with a mouse,
>   but it also occurs when the user focuses the element and hits enter or
>   space, and when the element is triggered via the accessibility API.

Comment: Wait, no, I don't buy it! What about accessibility for developers? No, more seriously, they must do it differently. At the very least, do not give me a `MouseEvent`.

Comment: yeah i agree, they could at least register the event as a keyboard event and then you could easily disable the click

Comment: If you think the solution is good enough, you can include it, I'll delete my own answer, yours is better

Comment: @Kaiido The problem is that your proposition works that's right, but is a trick. I found it out too, but I don't think it is safe to use, since this is not in the specification and looks sort of "dirty dodgy"

Comment: @jmore009 Figured out a way to do this :) http://stackoverflow.com/a/27891665/2680216